# Manually force reading environment spring property

Tags: spring, spring-boot

If we can use spring context in order to read properties which where already loaded from a property file, like this:

```
ctx.getEnvironment().getProperty("viva.val")
```

How can I get the above line getting an updated value once I manually cahnge the property file?

I have notice that the *getEnvironment().getProperty(...)* remember the old value, but I somehow wants to manually set a new value for the property, so the next time it gets called, it will be the new value, or even better, telling the context to read the property file again.

Is there any way to do that (Note, I'm not using singletone for the above code, and also not using @Value) without restart or spring cloud config.